# Is it possible to rotate the map in layout manager?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

QGIS 3.12 - Often I have property boundaries that would better fit on an A3 output if rotated 45-90 degrees from that represented in the map view. I can rotate in the map view but the layout manager does not respect this rotation. Is there anyway to rotate the map in the layout manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In element properties, you have an input field where you can roatate your map.

You could also use data driven override to exactly rotate the map to fit your features best to the map - for example using the new expression `main_angle` to get the main orientation of a polygon so that it fits best to your layout canvas.

[image]